# How to put the response of a post-request into a new window/tab

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, axios, fetch-api

I have this working example of how to use POST and put the server-generated html in a new window:

```
const response = await this.axiosInstance.post(url, postData)
const htmlResponse = response.data
const newWindow = window.open()
newWindow.document.write(htmlResponse)
```

However I'm not sure if this is the best or even correct way to do it. I see a few warnings with this. I get a warning on the last line that *newWindow* is possibly '*null*'. If switching to TypeScript I am also not sure the type of *htmlResponse*. I would assume *Document*, but write() only supports *string*, so it might be the correct classification.

Is there a better way to put the content of a post-request into a new window?

Update: The content-type is of type *text/html; charset=UTF-8*, not sure if it changes anything.

Comment: Yes: create an invisible `<form method="post" action="the_url" target="_blank">`, insert the data as <input>s and finally .submit() it.

Comment: You can use fetch instead of the obsolete axios and do `const htmlResponse = await response.text();`. That should result in a string.

Comment: Using a form is difficult since i need special auth-headers, but fetch is of course a viable alternative.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there might be enough for your use case. One might recommend waiting for some form of a ready event before manipulating the DOM.

```
const newWindow = window.open();
newWindow.onload = (event, f, g, h) => newWindow.document.write('Do great things.');
```

A much better solution might be fetching actual data instead of an HTML string from the server, creating a template page to receive the data, and rendering a well-formatted page.

The [Window.postMessage() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) could be used to send data between parent and child windows. This is especially useful if you need to circumvent the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

I have made several assumptions, and this suggestion might not work for your use case.